# passing values to nlog custom target

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, nlog

I have created a custom nLog target and it is working except for one thing.
I want to pass the logged in person name to the target, I have created a property called `ApplicationUser` which will pick up value.

The target definition looks like this :

```
<target name="MemoryTrace" 
        xsi:type="CustomTraceListener" 
        ApplicationUser="${identity:authType=False:isAuthenticated=False}"  />
```

But when the customTarget recieves the value of ApplicationUser, it does not get resolved to logged in person's name it just stays as `${identity:authType=False:isAuthenticated=False}`.

This is all as per the nLog [documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How%20to%20write%20a%20Target)

I have tested this with other targets and it gets resolved. What is it that I have to do to resolve it to username ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your `ApplicationUser` with the type `Layout` then you can get the current user with "rendering the layout" using the `ApplicationUser.Render(logevent)`:

```cs
[Target("CustomTraceListener")]
public sealed class MyFirstTarget : TargetWithLayout
{

    public Layout ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        string logMessage = this.Layout.Render(logEvent);
        string applicationUser = ApplicationUser.Render(logEvent);
        // ... Write where you want
    }
}
```